# Django - Loading Images From Folders Within Media Folder

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm having an issue where I can't load images from anywhere but my media folder.

For example:

```
<img src="media/image.png" />
```

will load just fine

however if i move the "image.png" file 1 more folder deeper to:

```
<img src="media/folder/image.png" />
```

"image.png" will not load.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: What is your configuration, you're running django on localhost, apache, something else? Also what values to do you have in settings.py for STATIC_URL variable? Finally what error message are you getting when the error happens? Is it 404?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this is on localhost. For the moment I was just hard coding this in an html file, so would it matter what my STATIC_URL value was? if it does matter it is '/static/'. I get no error messages, it isn't an error, the image just isn't loading if it's not located directly in the media folder

Comment: Is {% load static %} working fine for you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use django staticfiles module. 'Static' figures out where your files are placed and redirects all requests to this folder

Assuming that your image.png is located in you/yourapp/static/media/folder the following should do.

```
{% load  static %}
<img src="{% static 'media/folder/image.png' %}" />
```

[Read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-css-images) about serving static files with django.

Answer (score 0):

If not in production then perhaps this would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672594/1953366

It worked for me. You can use "/" for PATH to directly map the files. Folder hierarchy is not exposed though.