# How to serve a directory of static files at a custom url in django

Tags: django, static-files

I'm working on a django app that has static files being served from http://host/static.

I have a new folder full of static html/js/css that needs to be accessible at http://host/staff.

How can I tell django to serve the /staff files from that url?

Using nginx or some other proxy is not an option, and neither is changing the url.

I was able to get it partially working by adding `urlpatterns += static('/staff/', document_root='staff')`, but that only works while `Debug = True`.

Comment: what is your front end? normal jinja?

Comment: Yep, afaict this is a pretty standard django app. Seems like something like this should be trivial but I don't know the right configuration. The /staff files are totally plain html, no templating there at all.

Comment: add the {%load staticdata%} bracket at the top of the page?

Comment: What do you mean by "serve the /staff files"? You want Django's development server to serve these static files? Why do you want this?

Comment: Yes, I want the django app to serve the static files. I'm not asking for an architecture review - this is a project requirement that is out of my control. In RoR, this would be as simple as moving the /staff folder into /public. In Node.js/Express, you'd just write `app.use('/staff', express.static('staff'))`. I would like to know how to achieve the same functionality with django.

Answer (score 4):

Modified from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#static:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

PATH = '/custom-static-files/'
ROOT = '/var/www/html/custom-static-files/'

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(PATH, document_root=ROOT)
```

ROOT is the path of the folder you want to serve.  It should be an absolute path to the files on the operating system.

PATH is the path that the files will be served at.  If your website is https://example.com and you set `PATH = '/custom-static-files/` then the files would be served at https://example.com/custom-static-files/

Answer (score 1):

`./manage.py runserver` is development server of Django. It 'magically' serves static files from all `<app>/static/` (and from more locations if you add `STATICFILES_DIRS=`).

They are visible on `STATIC_URL=`, typically `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` is set.

If you want other urls, add following into `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path(<url>, <function>),
] + static('/<otherurl>/', document_root='<path>/<otherstaticdir>/')
```

However in production it should be done differently. You should collect static files from all `<app>/static/` and from additional `STATICFILES_DIRS` into single directory as defined via `STATIC_ROOT=`.

From there django tools like Whitenoise can serve the static files (taking care about caching and cache invalidating when you change a static file).

Or nginx can be configured not to send requests for static files to gunicorn+django (or uwsgi+django) but serve them directly.

Same, ie. Whitenoise or Nginx you can connect to your additional `<otherstaticdir>` accessible on the `<otherurl>`.