# How to serve images inside the document root folder using django and apache

Tags: django, apache

I have deployed a django app using apache. Am using an app called django-ads which allows me to upload images. The app dumps the images inside the  BASE_DIR folder so the image url is http://ip-address/iphone.jpeg when it is displayed on an html page.

Below is how my conf file looks:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/mysite/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess advert-admin python-home=/home/joe/advert-admin/venv 
    python-path=/var/www/html
WSGIProcessGroup advert-admin

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    Options FollowSymlinks
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /var/www/html/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I get a 404 error every time an image is loaded.

How can serve the images inside /var/www/html folder using Apache so that http://ip-address/iphone.jpeg does not return a 404?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't make much sense. If your Django site is at the root, how are you expecting to also serve images from that path? And why have you copied them into BASE_DIR at all?

Comment: Don't host django on root. You need to configure your app django-ads so thats it uploads images in static/img/ or anywhere inside static folder. Also in production its not a good idea to host static files on the same server, use something like AWS s3 for that

Comment: If not in production, then this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52672594/1953366